# How to launch IDLE3 on macOS Monterey?

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

So I now have both Python 2.7.18 and 3.8.9 pre-installed on my MacBook Pro with Monterey ([Does macOS Monterey come with Python3 preinstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392982/does-macos-monterey-come-with-python3-preinstalled)).

But how can I launch IDLE3? When I issued the command "idle3" in Terminal, it returned "command not found: idle3".  Does it mean that IDLE3 hasn't been pre-installed along with Python3?

In addition, should I install the most updated version of Python?

I am trying to learn Python.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, install the month-old python 3.10.1 from python.org.  It comes with a recent tcl/tk 8.6.12.something that works with python tkinter, which IDLE uses for its GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system python doesn't come with IDLE, since it's there to support system functions primarily.

Install your own copy, either with the official installers, or with `homebrew` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Max. But when I issued the command "idle" in Terminal, it did launch the Python 2.7.18 Shell (although in a black window, which was the same when I make a new file or open an existing file. I couldn't see anything when I typed in the file).  Do I have any misunderstanding?

Comment: It probably ships with idle2.7 due to backwards compatibility issues, but as you noted, it doesn't actually seem to work.  Again, you should install your own version, and not really on the system python except for toy stuff, since the version can change unpredictably

Comment: I just now installed Python3 by using homebrew. It installed version 3.9.9, rather than 3.10.1 from python.org as mentioned by Terry. The installation message said that "Tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately: brew install python-tk@3.9".

Comment: Is there a way to update the installation to 3.10.1? I tried "brew upgrade python" and "brew upgrade python3" but failed.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to specifically request python@3.10, which doesn't appear to be the default yet. 
 https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.10#default